# Capitalizing company name

Tags: logo, branding

I was wondering if there is a rule for how to design a company name inside a logo when it consists of 2 words without space.

For example if someone named his company as:

RightAway or rightaway or RIGHTAWAY

another example like:

HandsOn or handson or HANDSON

and if there is a difference if the words doesnt make any sense when they are combined like:

PhoneLamp or phonelamp or PHONELAMP.

Thank you

Comment: Which does the company like?

Comment: The company is a programming company abd they liked both cases of (for example) Right<Away> and right<away> and I was wondering if there os something more that I didnt think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *no rules* for logo creation.

Whatever works to convey the brand is the best option. If that brand sees the name of the company as imperative, then camel case (uppercase letters mid-word) may be a good idea.

FedEx, BlackBerry, PayPal, among others choose camel case as well as a tonal variation - i.e. "Fed" in blue, "Ex" in orange - "Pay" in dark blue, "Pal" in light blue.

Basically.. it's whatever works.

However, one should be always take into account how combined words, *without* any camel case, **may** be unintentionally read...

- handson -- HandsOn or HandSon?
- newshits -- NewsHits or NewShits?
- teachersexchange -- TeachersExchange or TeacherSexChange?

Camel case helps ensure proper intended reading at times. The purpose of camel case is to *visually* introduce some separation between the combined words.

---

Based on the comment under the question.. if there is a separator, such as `<` in `right<away>`, then it *really* doesn't matter.  With a separator present, the visual differentiation is already present. So, case becomes largely irrelevant.

Comment: +1 You've to watch for close matches too, 'TofuKing' doesn't read well, 'Clint' should never be written in all-caps & we all know that 'buy one get one free' actually ended up being pronounced as a new acronym,  bog off ;)